# json-server middleware not working as expected

Tags: node.js, express, json-server

*using node.js/Express/json-server*

I am trying to check ( and modify) the request url sent to my API json-server. I wrote as stated the following middleware in my app server.js

```
//  API JSON-SERVER
const jsonServer = require('json-server')
const apiServer = jsonServer.create()
const apiMiddlewares = jsonServer.defaults()
apiServer.use(apiMiddlewares)
...
apiServer.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('REQUEST: ', req)  
  next() // Continue to JSON Server Router  
})
...
apiRouter = jsonServer.router(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'server', 'db-dev.json'))
app.use('/api', apiRouter)
```

but I never get the request displayed
where am I wrong ?

Comment: where is app declared?  shouldn't be apiServer.use('/api', apiRouter)

Comment: I am using ( dev) the same web server ( Express) and db server ( at /api), app is defined above this block ..   var app = express()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked here

https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/253

and it seems to me that you never want to instantiate the jsonServer, but only use the router.  Since you are using the express server, you should attach the middleware to that.

```
const express = require('express')
const jsonServer = require('json-server')

const app = express()

app.use((req, res, next) => {
 console.log('REQUEST: ', req)  
 next() // Continue to JSON Server Router   
})

app.use('/api', jsonServer.router(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'server', 'db-dev.json')))
```

Comment: that's what I wrote...  my concern is related to the middleware...
apiServer.use((req, res, next) => {})   Do you mean I better use  
app.use((req, res, next) => {}) ?

Comment: you right ... I can also filter only the requests to the API :  
pp.use('/api', (req, res, next) => {})